# Displaying factors of a number

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, factorization

I want to display every factor of a number typed in a textfield to achieve this I tried using an array. But I am always getting the error `'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'` . Any suggestions to eliminate this error?

```
       NSMutableArray *array;
        array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];

        for (factorsNumber=1; factorsNumber<=number; factorsNumber++) {
            if (number%factorsNumber == 0) {
                [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", factorsNumber]];
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= [array count]; i++) {
            factors.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i, [[array objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
        }
```

Comment: The code works. But it is only displaying the first object in my array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= [array count]; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i <= [array count] - 1; i++) {
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
```

The valid indices of an `n`-element array are 0 to `n-1`.

Comment: Thanks now it works. But instead of giving me every factor of the number it only gives me the first one.

Comment: Probably because of `factorsNumber<=prime`. Shouldn't that be `factorsNumber<=number`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, hadn't refreshed. I think more code is needed to diagnose it, then.

Comment: In the snippet you have posted, I see no reason why it would only add one factor to the array. Perhaps the surrounding code would give a hint.

Comment: Except, you set `factor.text = ...`. Maybe you should append to `factors.text`? (I don't know obj-c, so the guess could be totally off.)

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, remove the = so that it reads:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

you problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) { // < instead of <=
    factors.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i, [[array objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
}
```